# How do I tell if my application is run for the first time?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a personal project and I want to walk new users through a tutorial if the application is run for the first time. I'm not quite sure how to do this and a google result didn't turn up anything (at least not with laymen search terms).

This is the first time I'm having to deal with this situation, but I would think the proper way to do this is to have a boolean and a property file of some sort.

Can someone shed some light on this or tell me what terms I need to google so I can read up on it.

**Edit**

Jeeze, never knew so many people would downvote a legitimate question that I don't know much about. I wasn't even asking for a direct answer, even a search term was fine as long as I knew what to search for...

Comment: is it a web application?

Comment: @Sai No, just a desktop application.

Comment: If it's a desktop app, it is typical to store user information in a file at ~/.appname.  Just checking for this files existance should work in your case.  You could register a line in this file "tutorialHasBeenRun=true"

Comment: @ChrisCM Assuming the application isn't one that installs (ie someone just runs the jar from the desktop), it wouldn't have a filepath would it?

Comment: ~/ stands for the users root directory, I forget how to access this in Java, but it is simple.  This is the strength behind this method.  Each user will get prompted to run the tutorial, and no configuration needs to be done.

Comment: @WilliamShatner I wouldn't worry too much about the downvotes, in the upvoter vs downvoter war you seem to have come out on top reputation wise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A boolean check should do fine; stored in a file, a database or in the registry.

Comment: But where would the file be stored? Assuming it is the first time run (no installation), it doesn't know where to write the file yet.

Comment: in the application's path, most likely (wherever the exe is), but you can of course define this yourself.

Comment: Could use the `%temp%` location?

Comment: @Alfie My friend (who is an IT tech) was very annoyed with me when I wrote an application like that. Apparently an application shouldn't touch its install directory (eg program files) after the initial install, it should be in the user's directory (I have noticed more and more programs doing this in real life; eg save games in my documents)

Comment: Well I suppose it depends on your development environment, if making a ClickOnce application with C#, everything is stored in the user's directory anyway isn't it? But also, the comment above asked to assume no installation. Finally, I wasn't suggesting where to store it, rather answering the question of where it would be stored [by default] :)

Comment: @Alfie Thats a fair point (I hate it when important information is in the comments!)

Comment: @RichardTingle I was thinking of placing it in My Documents, but I wasn't sure if that was proper or not. **At zEro** I guess I could use temp, and perhaps move it to the desired location after the tutorial is finished.

Comment: @WilliamShatner I'm no expert but if its not installed then ultimately whereever the end user decides to put it is the proper place for it (possibly thats even true if it is installed but then you can at least suggest).